# Issue in managing Actors of AKKA

Tags: akka

I am new to Akka,we are building a robust system for multiple transactions which can scale up to 5000 requests per minute.Our architecture is as follows

1. A scheduler pushes the list or request to Akka Main Actor
2. Akka Main Actor which has references of Subactors say "Ask" on the the subactors and waits for future,where subactors interact with "webservice adapters" where adapters inturn call's webservices
3. In "webservice adapters" we are storing the request and response to Database
4. Once the response is available, the adapter returns back the result to Subactor followed to Future for further processing in Actor.

Here is the problem:

Since we are using 'Ask' in the main actor for calling subactors, the main actor waits for some time and timeouts if the response is not returned with in expected time.

The response delay is happening since the adapter is writing the request and response to the database which may not get sufficient connections as the main actor spawns more requests parallel at a time, this is leading to DB connection congestion.

In order to resolve this I have created one more SubActor (DBActor) which has logic to save the request and response to DB and the reference of the subactoris created in subactors of mainactor and passed the reference to "Webservice Adapters". Here in adapter I am calling DBActor `Reference.tell(request,ActorRef.noSender())` which is asynchronous call. Now adapter doesn't wait for Database transaction and returns response to subactors with very less time ,and also there is no DB congestion now since DBActor takes care of messages.

I want to know is this a good thing to call DBActor in subactor by creating reference of DBActor in preStart() of Subactor.

I see so many dead letters as I am using main actors dispatcher and default unbounded mail box.

Can you suggest a better approach? I see so may errors with the above.

Comment: Do you have any requirements regarding ordered processing of the requests ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding one more layer of indirection is fine. I think your best pattern would be something along these lines:

1) The entry point actor receives a request and assign it a unique id

2) The entry point actor spawns a worker and pass the request to it together with the id (tell)

3) The worker actor waits for a connection, does his deeds, and responds to the main actor (tell) that he has completed that request (id) + optional result value

4) The main actor completes the external request.

This completely removes any ask pattern. Downside: no ordering guaranteed (you could achieve the ordering by caching the responses in the main entry point and sorting them).

If you need to timeout anyway (web connections) you can set a timer on the worker actor to die after a while.